# LazyInitializationException despite of OpenSessionInViewFilter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, lazy-initialization

I develop webapp using Spring 4, Hibernate 4 and JSF 2.2. I'm trying to use OpenSessionInViewFilter to avoid LazyInitializationException but I fail. I have class **Consultant** with such field:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "consultant")
private List<Product> products;
```

Now in other class where I have my **Consultant** object and I'm trying to get products using above field:

```
List<Product> products = consultant.getProducts();
```

Then LazyInitializationException is thrown. It's my log (I can't see any suspect things there):

```
Using SessionFactory 'sessionFactory' for OpenSessionInViewFilter
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sessionFactory'
Opening Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@f8b7e57f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f8b7e57f: Principal: User{userId=1, username=doradca@doradca.pl, password=$2a$10$ALqnZKxx9anO/4XnBjtt1Ocm4GC1KDfrAlIz/iV66RWANklk31WqW, authorities=[Authority{role=CONSULTANT}], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9ED9D61F10507CAF3B77109D465B9AD6; Granted Authorities: Authority{role=CONSULTANT}'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
pathInfo: both null (property equals)
queryString: both null (property equals)
requestURI: arg1=/EuroBroker/consultant/products.xhtml; arg2=/EuroBroker/consultant/products.xhtml (property equals)
serverPort: arg1=8080; arg2=8080 (property equals)
requestURL: arg1=http://localhost:8080/EuroBroker/consultant/products.xhtml; arg2=http://localhost:8080/EuroBroker/consultant/products.xhtml (property equals)
scheme: arg1=http; arg2=http (property equals)
serverName: arg1=localhost; arg2=localhost (property equals)
contextPath: arg1=/EuroBroker; arg2=/EuroBroker (property equals)
servletPath: arg1=/consultant/products.xhtml; arg2=/consultant/products.xhtml (property equals)
Removing DefaultSavedRequest from session if present
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f8b7e57f: Principal: User{userId=1, username=doradca@doradca.pl, password=$2a$10$ALqnZKxx9anO/4XnBjtt1Ocm4GC1KDfrAlIz/iV66RWANklk31WqW, authorities=[Authority{role=CONSULTANT}], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9ED9D61F10507CAF3B77109D465B9AD6; Granted Authorities: Authority{role=CONSULTANT}'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
/consultant/products.xhtml at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
Checking match of request : '/consultant/products.xhtml'; against '/consultant/**'
Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /consultant/products.xhtml; Attributes: [hasRole('CONSULTANT')]
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f8b7e57f: Principal: User{userId=1, username=doradca@doradca.pl, password=$2a$10$ALqnZKxx9anO/4XnBjtt1Ocm4GC1KDfrAlIz/iV66RWANklk31WqW, authorities=[Authority{role=CONSULTANT}], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, enabled=true}; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@2cd90: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 9ED9D61F10507CAF3B77109D465B9AD6; Granted Authorities: Authority{role=CONSULTANT}
Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@16ed6204, returned: 1
Authorization successful
RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
/consultant/products.xhtml reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
Entering JSF Phase: RESTORE_VIEW 1
Entering JSF Phase: RENDER_RESPONSE 6
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'accountManager'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'insuranceService'
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'insuranceService'
Chain processed normally
SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
Closing Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@373d727a -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
Creating new transaction with name [com.efsf.eurobroker.user.logic.TokenCleanerCron.deleteOldTokens]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6383a319 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4c7576d0)
Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@330b16dd]
Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
Found thread-bound Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
Participating in existing transaction
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache ----> CACHE HIT
checkoutStatement: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 4; checked out: 1; num connections: 1; num keys: 4
checkinStatement(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 4; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 4
Initiating transaction commit
Committing Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 4; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 4
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner@7f0b008a: Adding task to queue -- com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@5149a61d
trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@6383a319 [managed: 5, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@4c7576d0)
checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 4; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 4
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@373d727a -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@373d727a -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

In **web.xml** I addded (before any other filters):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>sessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>      
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

How do I get exception and how to avoid this one? I tried also OpenSessionInViewInterceptor but didn't work or I was doing something wrong.

I spent many many hours trying to solve this problem, reading many topics and tutorials but nothing helped me.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The `OpenSessionInViewFilter` will open a session as soon as a request comes in and closes it after the request has finished processing. Now if a new request comes in it doesn't reattach anything, so if you first retrive your `Consultant` and expect that it still is alive during the next request you will fail as that isn't the case and that isn't how the filter works.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then I would have to What would be good solution in such retrieve my Consultant from database again, right? Is it the only way or can I do something better?

Comment: Your controller (your jsf bean I suspect in this case) should prepare the data for the view so if you need it then retrieve it before hand. Else retrieve the object again for the next request (or reattach it to a new session).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Anyway doesn't exist any way to do something (using AOP, filter or something other) to avoid manually retrieving (refreshing) entity? I mean automatically reattaching hibernate session or something like that.